# Study the convergence of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)^p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Ex**: Study the convergence of the following series: $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)^p}$$

I tried to solve the problem by breaking it in the following way:

**1)** For $p>0$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)^p}\leqslant\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^p}\leqslant\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$

By the integral test $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ the series converge for $p>1$.

**2)** For $p<0$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(x+n)^{-p}$, as $-p>0$ the sequence diverges once $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n(x+n)^{-p}=\infty$.

**3)** For $p=0$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ which diverges.

**Question:**

Is my answer  right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n * a_n $ converges if: 
 $a_n \to 0$, $a_n$ decreases monotonically and $a_n$ non-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ eventually $x+n>0$, we have that

- for $p>0$ the series converges by [Leibniz Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test)
- for $p>1$ the series converges absolutely by comparison with $\sum \frac1 {n^p}$
- for $p\le 0$ the series diverges

Comment: You know nothing about $x$, i.e not necessarily $x+n>0$...

Comment: @Galc127 eventually $x+n>0$

Comment: Can we evaluate the series at $x+n<0$? How so?

Comment: @PedroGomes The behaviuor of a series is determined by the tail and for $n$ sufficiently large we can assume $x+n>0$.

Comment: @PedroGomes Of course if we had a value for $x$ such that $x+n=0$ the series would be not well defined for that single value, but eliminating that value the behaviour is determined by the tail.